# SPP Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have an old bluetooth keyboard which is really comfortable to use. However it uses the SPP protocol to send the keystrokes, which is not supported by most of the modern devices.

I thought that if there is any device I will be able to use it with, it is my linux laptop.

First of all I paired the keyboard with the laptop. It is able to being paired to, but not connected to. Then I tried to find any information about what to do next. However, the only things I came across are the manuals about pairing android and linux via SPP, which is not what I want to achieve.

I understand, that now I need to somehow listen to the keyboard, get the keystrokes and make them appear as real keyboard buttons being pressed, but there is no information I am able to find.

Comment: I can help with the "make them appear as real keyboard buttons" part, but I don't know enough about BT. Once you successfully pair, do you get any devices? What does `dmesg` or `syslog` say after pairing? That might give a hint where to look for keypress events.